# Datagridview Change cell color of non empty cell

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, colors

Im creating a calendar appointment application, Id like to change the color of the datagridview of the non empty cell (those with value) upon loading/opening the application.
my application already handles how to load the data.
i'm able to change the color of the non empty cell but after closing and opening again the color is back to default.

Im not sure with the correct syntax , or if i need to go through all the cells like  do a loop for the entire table and change the cell back color.

VB.net 2012

so my questions is like or the loop i wanted to attain is ;

if the cell is not empty then change cell.color
thanks for any help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I manage to solve it:

```
Dim dgv As DataGridView = Me.TblCalendarDataGridView

    For i As Integer = 0 To dgv.Rows.Count - 1
        For ColNo As Integer = 4 To 7
            If Not dgv.Rows(i).Cells(ColNo).Value Is DBNull.Value Then

                dgv.Rows(i).Cells(ColNo).Style.BackColor =  vbcolor.blue
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   'try this.........
   For i As Integer = 0 To DtGrd.Rows.Count - 1
        For ColNo As Integer = 4 To 7
            If Not DtGrd.Rows(i).Cells(ColNo).Value Is DBNull.Value Then

                DtGrd.Rows(i).Cells(ColNo).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
            End If
        Next
    Next
```