# Color empty space on DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to created a method where I can color the empty/null space on the datagridview. It is possible to do that? I was digging on that content but what I've found didn't solved my problem.

You know any method to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Datagridview Change cell color of non empty cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19193823/datagridview-change-cell-color-of-non-empty-cell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this methode to that :

```
Sub SetColorEmptyCellGrid(grid As DataGridView, myColor As Color)
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In grid.Rows
        For i As Integer = 0 To row.Cells.Count - 1
            If row.Cells(i).Value Is Nothing OrElse row.Cells(i).Value Is DBNull.Value OrElse String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.Cells(i).Value.ToString()) Then
                row.Cells(i).Style.BackColor = Color.Blue
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

and you call method for example with :

```
SetColorEmptyCellGrid(DataGridViewName, Color.Red)
```

Comment: It really solved my problem of course it will change color if it's null but it isn't possible to not change the color on the rows that will show the new data insert

Comment: You can recall a method after insert!

Comment: Instead of recall the method after insert, i suggest you to call "SetColorEmptyCellGrid" at the end of your DataGridView refresh method

Comment: The problem is that I am using F5 do refresh the database on datagridview but and it just add a new row if a different value exists if not it just update on the other rows. You know what I mean?

Comment: try to call  method "SetColorEmptyCellGrid" in code refresh (F5).